# Proper Method to Add weights to variables

Tags: predictive-models, modeling, categorical-encoding

Given a dataset with different fields of criteria, all coded as 1 or 0, and also with a target which can take a value of 1 or 0, how can I create weights into the fields. In a banking example, let say I have these data:

```
has_car - 1
has_house - 0
has_job - 1
(target) - 1
```

I want a model that will give me weights to the fields so that I would be able to predict or give a score to new data

```
has_car 0.2
has_house 0.1
has_job 0.5
```

What would be a proper statistical method to use?

Comment: Logistic regression?

Comment: What are you trying to predict?

Answer (score 1):

By *weights* you probably means coefficients (or "betas"). You did not give us much, but a natural starting point is to try logistic regression.  Search this site.